# Simplification of function $F(A,B,C,D) = \sum\left(0,2,4,5,8,9,10,12,13\right)$ using Karnaugh Map.

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

I have been given the function $F(A,B,C,D) =  \displaystyle \sum\left(0,2,4,5,8,9,10,12,13\right)$, to simplify using K-Map.
I drew the K map shown below:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\large AB\backslash CD\normalsize &00 &01 &11 &10 \\\hline
00 &1 &0 &0 &1 \\
01 &1 &1 &0 &0 \\
11 &1 &1 &0 &0 \\
10 &1 &1 &0 &1 \\\hline
\end{array}
I grouped the elements as 
$$\text{quad 1} =  m_0 + m_2 + m_8 + m_{10}$$
$$\text{quad 2} =  m_4 + m_5 + m_{12} + m_{13}$$
$$\text{quad 3} =  m_8 + m_9 + m_{12} + m_{13}$$
In total I formed 3 quads, however my tutor on discussing the solution told that the correct grouping is not including the above mentioned quad 1 and forming a separate quad and pair instead which is :
 $$\text{quad new} =  m_0 + m_4 + m_{12} + m_{8}$$
$$\text{pair 1 } =  m_2 + m_{10}$$
The reason he gave was that the new grouping forms more no. of groups(4) than the previous grouping(3)and hence it will be the correct grouping.
However I am not convinced as the rule says that we have to form the largest possible group, which here is the quad 1 instead of pair 1.
I would really apreciate any help here and some light on the "true rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal components (maximal covering, minimal number of letters) in your Karnaugh map are

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the first one become redundant?

Comment: Yes, it would. My aim was to put them all - to show that the function can be obtained with the use of pairs.